# OpenCV videocapture several cameras

Tags: windows, opencv

several GigE cameras shall be read out using OpenCV. How can I identify an individual camera? How is the camera index (open(deviceID)) build?

Thanks for your help!

Ciao
Holger

Answer (score 0):

I would use the camera maker's own SDK to control the cameras, especially if you need good performance (eg large images, high frame rate) or need to set camera specific parameters (eg exposure time) and then pass the data returned into openCV for processing and display.

Comment: Thank you. We will do so. But do you know, how the deviceID the OpenCV system uses is build?